# .ebextensions not updating php.ini configuration

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

in my .ebextensions folder I have "project.config"

```
files:
  "/etc/php.d/project.ini" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      upload_max_filesize=64M
      post_max_size=64M
```

The whitespace is all spaces (not tabs).

No matter what variant of this I try, I cannot escape the 2M default limit imposed by PHP by default. (I have a phpinfo() page that is showing me the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size is not updating.

4 hours - cannot find the solution - going absolutely crazy!! hopefully someone can turn my frown upsidedown!

Thanks!

Comment: I also have another file in that directory... but it shouldnt be affecting anything - its for SSL. 

`Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0`

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed it.

ebextensions/* was in my .gitignore (as aws even recommends)

I took it out of .gitingore, added it to the repo and then redeployed.

Far out.

I think its a flaw that eb deploy wants to look at files inside a git repo. These things should be environment independend in my opinion.

Anyhow.

It's fixed and I can breath again.

Comment: only after 24 hours

Comment: Oh really? Didn't know that. Thanks.